# Список мультидиалогов(бесед) VkApi. Идентификатор chat_id

Tags: java, android, vkontakte-api

Использую *VkApi*. Ознакомлен с методом `getDialogs`: он возвращает все диалоги. И ЛС и беседы. Требуется как-то их разделить. Также я в курсе про `getChat` и тому подобные методы, но все они требуют `chat_id`, который я не знаю как получить. Короче, как получить список бесед (чатов/мультидиалогов, если угодно)?

```
VKRequest req = VKApi.messages().getDialogs(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.COUNT,100));
req.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
        super.onComplete(response);
        VKApiGetDialogResponse getDialogResponse = (VKApiGetDialogResponse) response.parsedModel;
        list = getDialogResponse.items;
        for (VKApiDialog dia : list) {
        //dia.chat_id - отсутсвует
        //Возможно нужно как либо привести dia к типу VKApiChat?
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

В массиве полученного объекта видно, что у диалогов и чатов разные поля. В беседах непустой title, есть chat_active, chat_id, users_count. В диалоге всего этого нет.

Так что нужно пробежаться по ответу getDialogs циклом и сортировать объекты самостоятельно.