# Альтернатива методу messages.getDialogs()

Tags: vkontakte-api

Мне нужно получить идентификаторы всех чатов пользователя. Я знаю, что для этого можно задействовать метод [messages.getDialogs](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getDialogs) (в ответе [Список мультидиалогов(бесед) VkApi. Идентификатор chat_id](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/804848/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BA-%D0%BC%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4-vkapi-%D0%98%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80-chat-id) эта тема раскрывается более подробно).

Но метод **messages.getDialogs** объявлен устаревшим в официальной документации. Есть какая-либо альтернатива ему (чтобы ничего не сломалось в недалеком будущем)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, все верно. Метод `messages.getDialogs` является устаревшим с версии API `5.80`, вот его новый аналог с дополнительными полями параметров [`messages.getConversations`](https://vk.com/dev/messages.getConversations).

Подробнее об этих изменениях описано в [здесь](https://vk.com/wall-28551727_5102).